# How to design captcha verification in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, captcha, human-readable

Please send me any link or documentation where i can see how to design captcha verification.Please tell me the concept how to design it

Comment: The concept? Have the user enter something that's easy for a human but hard for a computer to solve.

Comment: So build that, or use one of the dozens of available existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use captcha in your application, have a look at available captcha packages for Laravel here: http://packalyst.com/s/captcha

If you want to learn how to implement captcha, pick one of the more popular packages and have a look at the code / documentation.

Comment: Thanks,but I want to create it by my own